# Highcharts error #15, graph is displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sorting, highcharts

I have created this fiddle to show the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/q8p8945z/

My graph is displayed as it should be, but I still get [error #15](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) from highcharts.
Highcharts says this about the error:

> Highcharts Error #15
>
> Highcharts expects data to be sorted
>
> This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock
>   chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For
>   performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is
>   required that the implementer pre-sorts the data.

I fetch my data from the database using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`p`.`postId`) `posts`, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`p`.`created`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00') `dateTime` FROM `posts` `p` LEFT JOIN `hashtags` `h` ON `p`.`hashtagId` = `h`.`id` WHERE `h`.`accountId` = 1 AND `p`.`source` = :source GROUP BY `dateTime` ORDER BY `p`.`created` ASC
```

`p`.`created` is a timestamp, so naturally it should be sorted in ascending order I think.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: That's not the series format area-spline is expecting. Each `series.data` should be a list of values on the Y axis, not a list of lists. The dates should be values on the X axis, not in the list of lists on the Y axis. So in `xAxis.categories`, not in `series`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that javascript monthhs start at zero not one. Try this:

```
post.push(Date.UTC(postDateTime[1],postDateTime[2]-1,
   postDateTime[3],postDateTime[4])); // add post on correct date/time spot
```

Note the -1 in the month parameter.

http://jsfiddle.net/6s4bhro1/